# Open child window from outlook web addin

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to open a child window and publish events from parent window to child window in outlook web addin. It is working fine in browsers and mac outlook. But in windows outlook, it is opening in browsers directly and not having any communication with parent window and not listening to events. How can i fix this?

opening child window like this :

```
window.open(url, 'title', "width=600, height=400, center=true, useContentSize=true");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your looking for is the [Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins). This API includes everything you need to handle pop-up dialogs and communication between the add-in and external browser window across Windows, Web, iPad, and Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add parent url domain section.I just put some urls here.

`<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://login.live.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:44365/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>Base url 3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>`

in manifesto.xml file . I have also got same issue but resolve with it